# Android mediaPlayer.getDuration() return 0 or -1

Tags: android, url, android-mediaplayer, media-player, dropbox

I am creating online media player where we are playing song with the help of `URL`. In `Media Player` we are displaying Total time of song, for displaying time we are using `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` function but it always returning `-1`.

> When I am passing Drop Box URL then it working but when I pass my server URL (https://) then it not working.

```
2021-01-25 14:50:33.777 11438-11438/com.dd.xyz W/MediaPlayer: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2021-01-25 14:50:33.777 11438-11438/com.dd.xyz W/MediaPlayer: See the documentation of setAudioStreamType() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2021-01-25 14:50:33.778 11438-11438/com.dd.xyz V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@6a1c34b): Cookies: null
2021-01-25 14:50:33.783 11438-11663/com.dd.xyz V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@ea97e0b) exists.
2021-01-25 14:50:33.783 11438-11663/com.dd.xyz V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@6a1c34b): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@ea97e0b Cookies: null
2021-01-25 14:50:34.616 11438-11438/com.dd.xyz I/mediaFileLength: -1
```

Below is code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageViewPlayPause;
    private TextView textCurrenTime,textTotalDuration;
    private SeekBar playerSeekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler =new Handler();
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewPlayPause=findViewById(R.id.imagePlayPause);
        textCurrenTime=findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration=findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        playerSeekBar=findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);

        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);

        imageViewPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imageViewPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }
                else{
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imageViewPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
            }
        });
        prepareMediaPlayer();
        playerSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar) view;
                int playPosition=(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/100)*seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                textCurrenTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareMediaPlayer(){
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://varkarisanskruti.com/sample.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            Log.d("musicPlayerTimehere", String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private Runnable updater=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textCurrenTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        }
    };


    private void updateSeekBar(){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            playerSeekBar.setProgress((int)(((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaPlayer.getDuration())*100));
            handler.postDelayed(updater,1000);
        }
    }



    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds){
        String timerString="";
        String secondString;
        int hour=(int) (milliSeconds/(1000*60*60));
        int minutes=(int)(milliSeconds%(1000*60*60))/(1000*60);
        int seconds=(int)((milliSeconds%(1000*60*60))%(1000*60)/1000);
        if(hour>0){
            timerString=hour+":";
        }
        if(seconds<10){
            secondString="0"+seconds;
        }
        else {
            secondString=""+seconds;
        }
        timerString=timerString+minutes+":"+secondString;
        return timerString;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345298/mediaplayer-getduration-returns-0-only-in-my-server-files) but this is for Zero and I can't use third party lib due to privacy/company policies.

Please Help...

Thank you in advance for helping...!

Comment: If no duration is available (for example, if streaming live content), -1 is returned. See [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#getDuration()).

Comment: You mean I am streaming audio file from `URL` that's why it returning `0`? if so then what i need to do?

Comment: use `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` instead

Comment: I don't think you are correct because when i use `DropBox` URL it working but when i am trying from my server it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried multiple answers from `stackoverflow`, below are some for your reference but nothing is working -

[How to get mp3 file duration Http streamed over Android MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245123/how-to-get-mp3-file-duration-http-streamed-over-android-mediaplayer)

[mediaPlayer.getDuration() returns 0 after setDataSource and crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336221/mediaplayer-getduration-returns-0-after-setdatasource-and-crashes-app)

[MediaPlayer getDuration returns -1412558917](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469206/mediaplayer-getduration-returns-1412558917)

So I analyzed `.mp3` file properties and found that if `Bit Rate` is `128kbps` then `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` always returns `0` or `-1`.

I know you might don't believe that's why I recorded the video and uploaded it on Youtube. Here is link for your reference. https://youtu.be/-AKw59eb6nM

For me converting mp3 file to **320kbps** from **128kbps** is the solution.

Comment: Indeed, changing from 128kbps to 320kbps solved the problem of returning -1 to mediaplayer.getDuration()